# Count the subsequences of length 4 divisible by 9

Tags: algorithm, division

To count the subsequences of length 4 of a string of length n which are divisible by 9.

For example if the input string is 9999
then cnt=1

My approach is similar to Brute Force and takes O(n^3).Any better approach than this?

Comment: If the input string is 99999 (5 digits), what would count be? Do only unique subsequences count, or does each duplicate count separately?

Comment: @Steve314 Each duplicate count seperately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check if a number is divisible by 9, You better look [here](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/arithmetic/numbers/divisibility-rules-and-tests.php#divisibilityBy9).

I will describe the method in short:

```
checkDividedByNine(String pNum) :
If pNum.length < 1
   return false
If pNum.length == 1
   return toInt(pNum) == 9;
Sum = 0
For c in pNum:
    Sum += toInt(pNum)
return checkDividedByNine(toString(Sum))
```

So you can reduce the running time to less than O(n^3).

**EDIT:**
If you need very fast algorithm, you can use pre-processing in order to save for each possible 4-digit number, if it is divisible by 9. (It will cost you 10000 in memory)

**EDIT 2:**
Better approach: you can use dynamic programming:

For string S in length N:

D[i,j,k] = The number of subsequences of length j in the string S[i..N] that their value modulo 9 == k.

Where 0 <= k <= 8, 1 <= j <= 4, 1 <= i <= N.

```
D[i,1,k] = simply count the number of elements in S[i..N] that = k(mod 9).
D[N,j,k] = if j==1 and (S[N] modulo 9) == k, return 1. Otherwise, 0.
D[i,j,k] = max{ D[i+1,j,k], D[i+1,j-1, (k-S[i]+9) modulo 9]}.
```

And you return D[1,4,0].

You get a table in size - N x 9 x 4.

Thus, the overall running time, assuming calculating modulo takes O(1), is O(n).

Comment: That I know. I want to reduce the complexity of the problem.

Comment: If pNum.length < 1
   return false;

Why?

Why not return 0?

Comment: checkDividedByNine return boolean, not a number.

Comment: @Luv look at my dynamic programming solution

Comment: @barak1412 See me working code for the above problem using DP

Comment: It is easy - simple recursion with base cases. If you want, I can guide you.

Comment: @barak1412 Your solution is really very good. It has time complexity O(9*4*n). Could it be further optimized.

Comment: I guess you are talking about optimization not in terms of complexity. I will try think about some optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Assuming that the subsequence has to consist of consecutive digits, you can scan from left to right, keeping track of what order the last 4 digits read are in. That way, you can do a linear scan and just apply divisibility rules.</del>

If the digits are not necessarily consecutive, then you can do some finangling with lookup tables. The idea is that you can create a 3D array named `table` such that `table[i][j][k]` is the number of sums of `i` digits up to index `j` such that the sum leaves a remainder of `k` when divided by 9. The table itself has size 45n (`i` goes from 0 to 4, `j` goes from 0 to `n-1`, and `k` goes from 0 to 8).

For the recursion, each `table[i][j][k]` entry relies on `table[i-1][j-1][x]` and `table[i][j-1][x]` for all `x` from 0 to 8. Since each entry update takes constant time (at least relative to n), that should get you an O(n) runtime.

Comment: Numbers are not necessarily consecutive in a subsequence

Comment: If you're only looking for the total number, you can try some stuff with memoizing; I'll update my answer. (I was being silly earlier)

Comment: By the way, can you please explain me how is it O(n^3) or O(n^4)?

Comment: @Vikram Originally I was working under the assumption that we had to generate each group of 4 digits (of which there are n choose 4), which would have made it O(n^4). Then I found the smarter way to approach it.

Comment: @DennisMeng See me working code for the above problem using DP, it runs in linear time using lookup tables but it takes O(600n) in worst case and space O(n*4*10).
Please see if it could be further optimized
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
/*NOTE: The following holds true, if the subsequences consist of digits in contagious locations */ 

public int countOccurrences (String s) {
    int count=0;
    int len = s.length();
    String subs = null;
    int sum;

    if (len < 4)
        return 0;
    else {
        for (int i=0 ; i<len-3 ; i++) {
            subs = s.substring(i, i+4);
            sum = 0;

            for (int j=0; j<=3; j++) {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(subs.charAt(j)));
            }

            if (sum%9 == 0)
                count++;
        }           
        return count;
    }   
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in a comment to my question, the subsequences don't necessarily contain consecutive digits. Otherwise, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code for the above problem based on the above discussed ways using lookup tables

```
int fun(int h)
{
return (h/10 + h%10);
}

int main()
{
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
int i,T;
for(T=0;T<t;T++)
{
    char str[10001];
    scanf("%s",str);        
    int len=strlen(str);
    int arr[len][5][10];
    memset(arr,0,sizeof(int)*(10*5*len));

    int j,k,l;
        for(j=0;j<len;j++)
            {
              int y;
                y=(str[j]-48)%10;
                arr[j][1][y]++;
            }



        //printarr(arr,len);    





        for(i=len-2;i>=0;i--)   //represents the starting index of the string
            {


                    int temp[5][10];
                    //COPYING ARRAY
                    int a,b,c,d;
                    for(a=0;a<=4;a++)
                    for(b=0;b<=9;b++)
                    temp[a][b]=arr[i][a][b]+arr[i+1][a][b];


            for(j=1;j<=4;j++)   //represents the length of the string
                {
                for(k=0;k<=9;k++)   //represents the no. of ways to make it
                    {

                        if(arr[i+1][j][k]!=0)
                          {
                          for(c=1;c<=4;c++)
                            {
                              for(d=0;d<=9;d++)
                                 {
                            if(arr[i][c][d]!=0)
                                 {
                                int h,r;
                                r=j+c;
                                if(r>4)
                                continue;
                                h=k+d;                      
                                h=fun(h);
                                if(r<=4)
                                  temp[r][h]=( temp[r][h]+(arr[i][c][d]*arr[i+1][j][k]))%1000000007;
                              }}}
                        }






                    //copy back from temp array

                    }
                }
                for(a=0;a<=4;a++)
                    for(b=0;b<=9;b++)
                    arr[i][a][b]=temp[a][b];
            }








printf("%d\n",(arr[0][1][9])%1000000007);


}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It runs in linear time using lookup tables but it takes O(600n) in worst case and space O(n*4*10). Please see if it could be further optimized.
Thanks in advance